# How to decode an RFC 2047 encoded email header in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, tmail

I have the following header:

```
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Marta_Falc=E3o?= <marta.falcao@example.com.br>
```

I can easily split out the stuff before the `<`, which leaves me with

```
"=?iso-8859-1?Q?Marta_Falc=E3o?="
```

What can I use to turn this into `"Marta Falcão"`?

Comment: The header is encoded using the scheme from RFC 2047. Maybe that helps as a search term.

Comment: It did indeed! Not only is there a gem for that, https://github.com/ConradIrwin/rfc2047-ruby/, searching the TMail source for 2047 revealed a method I could use without adding a new dependency. Well done, @RolandIllig :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Roland Illig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225757/roland-illig) for his comment, which led me to two options:

1. install [rfc2047-ruby](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/rfc2047-ruby/) and call `Rfc2047.decode(header)`
2. install [TMail](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/) and call `TMail::Unquoter.unquote_and_convert_to(header, 'utf-8')` or better yet `TMail::Address.parse(header).friendly`, the latter of which strips out the `<email address>` part

Comment: First one worked fine for me! gem 'rfc2047', in my gem list, a restart, and call the method as described.. worked a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Using the newer [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem:

`Mail::Encodings.value_decode(str)` or
`Mail::Encodings.unquote_and_convert_to(str, to_encoding)`

Comment: FYI, there is an encoding bug in Mail::Encodings#value_decode, https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1397. My answer can help if you encoundered this bug.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby to implement [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) isn't hard:

```rb
module Rfc2047
  TOKEN = /[\041\043-\047\052\053\055\060-\071\101-\132\134\136\137\141-\176]+/.freeze
  ENCODED_TEXT = /[\041-\076\100-\176]+/.freeze
  ENCODED_WORD = /=\?(?<charset>#{TOKEN})\?(?<encoding>[QB])\?(?<encoded_text>#{ENCODED_TEXT})\?=/i.freeze

  class << self
    def encode(input)
      "=?#{input.encoding}?B?#{[input].pack('m0')}?="
    end

    def decode(input)
      match_data = ENCODED_WORD.match(input)
      raise ArgumentError if match_data.nil?

      charset, encoding, encoded_text = match_data.captures
      decoded =
        case encoding
        when 'Q', 'q' then encoded_text.unpack1('M')
        when 'B', 'b' then encoded_text.unpack1('m')
        end
      decoded.force_encoding(charset)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
Rfc2047.decode '=?iso-8859-1?Q?Marta_Falc=E3o?=' # => Marta_Falcão
```

**Update**

[mikel/mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1397) is currently having an [encoding issue](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1397) which might not decode the string correctly.

If that really bothers you, you can try `new_rfc_2047`:

```
$ gem install new_rfc_2047
$ ruby -rrfc_2047 -e 'puts Rfc2047.decode "From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Marta_Falc=E3o?= <marta.falcao@example.com.br>"'
From: Marta Falcão <marta.falcao@example.com.br>
```

Since the source code of mikel/mail is a little too complicated for me to do the modification, I just made my own gem for this.

Gem source is here: https://github.com/tonytonyjan/rfc_2047/